# Working with a PyCharm project in two different environments

Tags: pycharm

I have a PyCharm project which I edit in two different environments, Linux and Windows. The project itself is on Dropbox so I see the same files in both environments. 
In each environment, I have a slightly different Python interpreter on a different system path.
Whenever I configure the interpreter for the project on one environment, I see in the other environment that "no interpreter is configured for this project".

How can I configure the project so that it works in both environments?

Comment: will this help: for Linux `pip3 install virtualenv`, `virtualenv -p python3 ~/virtEnvPy3_user_provided`, `cd ~/virtEnvPy3_user_provided`, `source bin/activate`, same steps for windows with different folder structure, and in pycharm just point to different virtualenv on prompt.